# When should we close a question as "it belongs to superuser"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, superuser

Sometimes I see questions about `Visual Studio`, like these:

- [silent uninstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6293205/340760)
- [Visual Studio 2010 External Tools - How to automatically attach a debugger to the tool when it is started?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6293125/340760)
- [Deploying item/project VS2010 templates for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6290539/340760)

They are not really related to programming, it is more likely asking how to do something on the software itself.

Should them be migrated to Super User? When should we really vote to migrate to Super User?

Comment: the first question is iffy (why is it tagged VS?), the others seem on point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most questions about IDE's used during development are on-topic. The folks who troll SO are far more likely to have an IDE installed than the folks on SU by the definition of the sites alone. [Per the SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> - software tools commonly used by programmers

That being said, if it seems <strike>wildly off-topic</strike>unsuited for the site (e.g. *"what is your FAVO[U]RITE SHORTCUT"*) please vote to close.

Comment: If it's something like "What's your favorite keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio?" then it should be closed as subjective, not off-topic.

Comment: @Lance: fair enough, "not welcome here".