# How do I know whether a question belongs here or on Super User, or Server Fault?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There're Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and more — where should I ask my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66083/therere-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-more-where-should-i-ask-my-questio)

(Generalization of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94473/196834).)

Is there some basic set of rules-of-thumb about what belongs on Stack Overflow, Server Fault or Super User?

Comment: possible duplicate of [There're Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and more -- where should I ask my question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66083/therere-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-more-where-should-i-ask-my-questio) (and: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is pretty much in the first paragraph of the FAQ for all 3 sites ([here](https://superuser.com/faq), [here](https://serverfault.com/faq), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)), but in general, I usually think about it like this:

- Stack Overflow > Specific (and answerable) Programming related questions
- Super User > General computing issues dealing with home computer hardware and consumer grade software/operating systems
- Server Fault > Enterprise Network issues, and commercial grade software/hardware/operating systems

There is some overlap between Server Fault and Super User, but the guidelines I use for myself seem to target the correct audience.

Comment: Well, that overlaps quite a bit, but... I guess it'll have to do.

Comment: @EyalRozenberg The only real overlap is the small/medium business IT world where they are using consumer grade hardware, software, and networking.  For those issues, I'll generally go to SU for smaller or isolated problems with the hardware/software, and SF for widespread problems or networking issues.